# Wordpress Favourites Plugin - Read array of posts from cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, cookies, favorites

I need to read the cookie generated by "Wordpress Favourites" plugin (great code foundation), and get the posts ID's out of the cookie array for use in the interface. This is to avoid front-end caching at our hosting provider WP Engine.

The cookie is called "simplefavorites" the cookie data looks like this when viewed in Firebug console:

Under "value":

`[{"site_id":1,"posts":[17411,22578],"groups":[{"group_id":1,"site_id":1,"group_name":"Default List","posts":[17411,22578]}]}]`

and under "Raw Data":

`%5B%7B%22site_id%22%3A1%2C%22posts%22%3A%5B17411%2C22578%5D%2C%22groups%22%3A%5B%7B%22group_id%22%3A1%2C%22site_id%22%3A1%2C%22group_name%22%3A%22Default+List%22%2C%22posts%22%3A%5B17411%2C22578%5D%7D%5D%7D%5D`

I need to get the post values as an array to work with like array(17411,22578). We can return the entire cookie contents, and detect whether it exists, but yanking out just the ID's is proving to be tricky. Any suggestions on how to parse this string would be greatly appreciated. Here's what we're working with right now....

```
    // Read Cookie For Favorites Functionality - simplefavourites
    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
    // Extract post ID's from cookie string
    function getvaluefromcookiestring(cookiecontents){
        cookiecontents = decodeURI(cookiecontents); // this works fine and
        var val = JSON.parse(cookiecontents),
        v = val[0]; // the contents of the cookie is a one-node array
        return v.posts;
    }
    var cookiecontents = readCookie('simplefavorites');
    cookiecontents = getvaluefromcookiestring(cookiecontents);
    alert(cookiecontents);
```

We receive a "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ':' after property name in object at line 1 column 12 of the JSON data"

------PROBLEM SOLVED------
with the help of @Spartacus and @Louys Patrice Bessette. See related question here on retrieving values from a cookie correctly:
[Javascript - retrieving data from a cookie as "value" not "raw data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122768/javascript-retrieving-data-from-a-cookie-as-value-not-raw-data/46122895?noredirect=1#comment79212809_46122895)

```
    // Read cookie for favorites functionality - simplefavourites
    function readCookie(name) {
        var c = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]+)'));
        return c ? c[2] : null;
    }
    // Extract post ID's from cookie string
    function getvaluefromcookiestring(cookiecontents){
        cookiecontents = decodeURI(cookiecontents.replace(/%3A/g, ":").replace(/%2C/g, ",").replace(/\+/g, "%20"));
        var val = JSON.parse(cookiecontents),
        v = val[0];
        return v.posts;
    }
    var cookiecontents = readCookie('simplefavorites');
    cookiecontents = getvaluefromcookiestring(cookiecontents);
    alert(cookiecontents);
```

Thanks for all the help stackers!

Comment: As not to dilute this topic, retrieving cookie data with the right character translation has been moved to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122768/javascript-retrieving-data-from-a-cookie-as-value-not-raw-data
Will post back with the final combined solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your cookie-getter function to this:

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var c = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]+)'));
    return c ? c[2] : null;
}
```

Then use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to turn the value into an object for manipulation. You can grab it like so:

```
function getpostsfromfavouritecookie(cookiecontents){
        var val = JSON.parse(cookiecontents),
            v = val[0]; // the contents of the cookie is a one-node array

        return v.posts;
}

var cookiecontents = readCookie('simplefavorites');
var posts = getpostsfromfavouritecookie(cookiecontents);

alert(posts);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Spartacus, any idea why the "proposed solution" above is not returning correctly?

Comment: Clarified my answer

Comment: Thanks @Spartacus, could you help me assemble a code snippet that returns the value for posts key in the example array?, pointing me to the Json reference is helpful, but only half the way there. Without stringifying  "cookiecontents" it pulls a JS error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi @Spartacus, your a champ thanks for the help, still getting an error, see updated question above.

Comment: What is the value of "cookiecontents" before you pass it to be parsed? add console.log(cookiecontents) before `var posts...`

Comment: `cookiecontents = %5B%7B%22site_id%22%3A1%2C%22posts%22%3A%5B17411%2C22578%5D%2C%22groups%22%3A%5B%7B%22group_id%22%3A1%2C%22site_id%22%3A1%2C%22group_name%22%3A%22Default+List%22%2C%22posts%22%3A%5B17411%2C22578%5D%7D%5D%7D%5D
`
This is why I stringified on previous versions, this doesn't look like valid Json to me. Thoughts?

Comment: It's not, it's converted to html entities. If this is the way it's stored in the cookie (and it has to be, the code I gave you doesn't convert to entities), then you need to convert the entities to their characters. That's unfortunately out of the scope of this question. Do that first, then the above should work.

Comment: Thanks @Spartacus, now I can see why you deferred converting HTML entities to another question, it's a huge pain in the 4$$!.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122768/javascript-retrieving-data-from-a-cookie-as-value-not-raw-data

Comment: For sure, but it looks like you were given the correct answer on that post. Now check to see how everything works from this code with the correct JSON format.

Comment: still not quite solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122768/javascript-retrieving-data-from-a-cookie-as-value-not-raw-data
any thoughts you have on this other questions would be greatly appreciated @spartacus

Comment: Do you have a link to the plugin repo? We might investigate the plugin and see if we can stop it from uri encoding the JSON object

Comment: I'll give the answer cred caus you stuck with me on this one @spartacus ;-). Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be valid JSON. Use JSON.parse().

```
var cookieString = '[{"site_id":1,"posts":[17411,22578],"groups":[{"group_id":1,"site_id":1,"group_name":"Default List","posts":[17411,22578]}]}]';
var obj = JSON.parse(cookieString);
// now access object properties
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Thanks as well @pate, both these answers are right. Just need to to know how to return that value.