# Javascript - retrieving data from a cookie as "value" not "raw data"

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, cookies

Working with cookie created by "Wordpress Favourites" plugin, when retrieving the value from the cookie, using this suggested function.

```
    // Read Cookie For Favorites Functionality - simplefavourites
    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

We get the "RAW DATA" back... by this I mean the text you see when going to firebug -> cookies -> select cookie -> switch to "raw data" view.

It looks like this:

`%5B%7B%22site_id%22%3A1%2C%22posts%22%3A%5B17411%2C22578%5D%2C%22groups%22%3A%5B%7B%22group_id%22%3A1%2C%22site_id%22%3A1%2C%22group_name%22%3A%22Default+List%22%2C%22posts%22%3A%5B17411%2C22578%5D%7D%5D%7D%5D`

When what we actually want is the text from "value" which looks like this, for use in interface jQuery.

`[{"site_id":1,"posts":[17411,22578],"groups":[{"group_id":1,"site_id":1,"group_name":"Default List","posts":[17411,22578]}]}]`

I understand the only difference between these is character translation, but we really want to avoid the overhead of character translation every time this function runs just to retrieve a simple array of values from cookie.

Is there anyway of reading the cookie contents as the "value" rather then "raw data"?

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

------------PROPOSED SOLUTION---------------
working with feedback from @Louys Patrice Bessette

```
    // Read Cookie For Favorites Functionality - simplefavourites
    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
    var cookiecontents = readCookie('simplefavorites');
    cookiecontents = decodeURI(cookiecontents); 
    alert(cookiecontents);
```

This returns the cookie value as:
`[{"site_id"%3A1%2C"posts"%3A[17411%2C22578]%2C"groups"%3A[{"group_id"%3A1%2C"site_id"%3A1%2C"group_name"%3A"Default+List"%2C"posts"%3A[17411%2C22578]}]}]`

Which clears up some of the character translation but not all, looks like ":" and "," are not getting "decoded"

------------PROBLEM SOLVED---------------
working with feedback from @Louys Patrice Bessette

```
    // Read Cookie For Favorites Functionality - simplefavourites
    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
    var cookiecontents = readCookie('simplefavorites');
    cookiecontents = decodeURI(cookiecontents.replace(/%3A/g, ":").replace(/%2C/g, ",").replace(/\+/g, "%20"));
    alert(cookiecontents);
```

Comment: What's the overhead here really? A few microseconds? You have an escaped string in the cookie, so you you just have to `unescape()` it and then `JSON.parse()` it if you want it back as an object. Ideally you could set the cookie in a different manner to avoid this process.

Comment: Can you link the plugin repo?

Comment: Hi @Spartacus, we want to leave the plugin as is.... we're so close, don't think there's any need to go to this length.

Here is the repo:
https://github.com/kylephillips/favorites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That ain't "raw data", that is URL encoded string.

Use `decodeURI()` on the value returned by `readCookie()` if you expect the result to be an object, array or a string containing characters not allowed in an URL.

See the MDN [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) and a [W3C School example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp).

---

**EDIT**

Seems like your cookie was *strangely* encoded...

Some characters not needed to be encoded were...
And some needed weren't.

In your string, I found 3.

```
%3A ==> :
%2C ==> ,
+ ==> %20
```

So the way to correctly decode your cookie would be:

```
var correctlyDecoded = decodeURI(cookieVal.replace(/%3A/g, ":").replace(/%2C/g, ",").replace(/\+/g, "%20"));
```

You should have a close look at how your cookie gets encoded... Because it may happen to have some more characters in fault in other cookies.

You will be able to use [**this CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/wqVBZJ?editors=0010) to find those.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Louys, see updated answer above, doesn't seem to be correctly decoding all characters using decodeURI(). So close!

Comment: I found a solution **for this cookie** you posted... And the way to fix... But **not the cause**.

Comment: Thanks so much @Louys Patrice Bessette, I wish I could give yall a high five, the crisp'ness would be legendary. Works a charm.

Comment: Thanks!! I have to mention that it made my brain bleed a bit and my eyes to cross-side a lot on this one ;)

Comment: I just improved the CodePen tool with a cool library I used a couple months ago... [Diff, Match and Patch](https://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html) It makes the differences more easy to find.;)